# string searching with exclusions

Tags: c++, string

Firstly, I do not have the option to use Regular Expressions.  It pains me to say this.

My problem is I may have a `std::string` that might contain something like:

`std::string someString = "(U//DISTRIBUTION//DONE)"`.

What i'd like to do is search the string for just the captial U and nothing else around it.  In other words, I want to exclude and finds on a U that are surrounded by other letters.  Would it be better to tokenize on the delimeter or is there a better way?

Comment: "Requirement" of the project.  It is something well beyond my means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you pad your searchee string with leading and trailing `//` (if it's not already present) and then use `someString.find("//U//") != std::string::npos`.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the find method but wouldn't the "//U//" fail in the example posted in my question?

Comment: @Robb I realized that as soon as I entered the answer: fixed.